# function to call the different columns for calculating Correlation and Confidence interval using Bootstrap in R

Tags: r, function, loops

Here is the problem I am currently facing: I have a data frame (let's call A) of 200 observations (rows) and 12 variables (columns). where I am, trying to find out the confidence interval using Bootstrap based on Correlation between two variables in the data frame.

My Data:

```
library(boot)
library(tidyverse)
library(psychometric) 

hsb2 <- read.table("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv", sep=",", header=T)
```

here I am trying to find out the confidence interval by using bootstrap based correlation formula

I wrote code for that its work.

```
k<-CIr(r=orig.cor, n = 21, level = .95)
k
n<-length(hsb2$math)
#n

B<-5000
boot.cor.all<-NULL

for (i in 1:B){
  index<-sample(1:n, replace=T)
  boot.v2<-hsb2$math[index]
  boot.v1<-hsb2$write[index]
  boot.cor<-cor(boot.v1, boot.v2,method="spearman")
  boot.cor.all<-c(boot.cor.all, boot.cor)
}
ci_boot<-quantile(boot.cor.all, prob=c(0.025, 0.975))
ci_boot
 
Result:
[1] 0.6439442
[1] 0.2939780 0.8416635
     2.5%     97.5% 
0.5556964 0.7211145
```

Here is the actual problem I am facing where I have to write a function to get
result for another variable but

this function not working

```
bo<-function(v1,v2,df){
  orig.cor <- cor(df$v1,df$v2,method="spearman")
  orig.ci<-CIr(r=orig.cor, n = 21, level = .95)
  B<-5000
  n<-length(df$v1)
  boot.cor.all<-NULL
  for (i in 1:B){
    index<-sample(1:n, replace=T)
    boot.hvltt2<-df$v1[index]
    boot.hvltt<-df$v2[index]
    boot.cor<-cor(boot.hvltt2, boot.hvltt,method="spearman")
    boot.cor.all<-c(boot.cor.all, boot.cor)
  }
  ci_boot<-quantile(boot.cor.all, prob=c(0.025, 0.975))
  
  return(orig.cor,orig.ci,ci_boot)
}
```

after calling this function I am getting error

```
bo(math,write,hsb2)
bo(math,read,hsb2)
bo(female,write,hsb2)
bo(female,read,hsb2)
```

#### I am getting this error

```
Error in cor(df$v1, df$v2, method = "spearman") : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

## how to write a function correctly.

### I want the result as each time a call function it needs to be stored in data frame like below

```
Variable1 variable2  Orig Cor    Orig CI            bootstrap CI
math       wirte     0.643    0.2939780 0.8416635   0.5556964 0.7211145 
math       read       0.66    0.3242639 0.8511580   0.5736904 0.7400174 
female     read      -0.059    -0.4787978  0.3820967 -0.20432743  0.08176896 
female     write
science    write
science    read
```

Comment: In working code, please show the definition/assignment of *orig.cor*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic was right, I just had to make some changes on how you access the elements on `df`. R doesn't recognized the objects `math` and `write` because they are columns inside the data.frame. One way to pass them as arguments to the function is to define them as strings `v1 = "math"` and then access them with `df[,v1]`

```
bo<-function(v1,v2,df){
  orig.cor <- cor(df[,v1],df[,v2],method="spearman") 
  orig.ci<-CIr(r=orig.cor, n = 21, level = .95)
  B<-5000
  n<-nrow(df) #Changed length to nrow
  boot.cor.all<-NULL
  for (i in 1:B){
    index<-sample(1:n, replace=T)
    boot.hvltt2<-df[index,v1]
    boot.hvltt<-df[index,v2]
    boot.cor<-cor(boot.hvltt2, boot.hvltt,method="spearman")
    boot.cor.all<-c(boot.cor.all, boot.cor)
  }
  ci_boot<-quantile(boot.cor.all, prob=c(0.025, 0.975))

  return(list(orig.cor,orig.ci,ci_boot)) #wrap your returns in a list
}

bo("math","write",hsb2)
```